# How to retrieve value/name of <a href..> to PHP variable when modal is involved

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a modal that is common to all the href links, but I need to pass the value of the href so that I can set a PHP session variable to further use info of the href clicked.

For example:
If I click href Tokyo, I need to set a session variable 'prefecture' to 'Tokyo', if I click 'Kanagawa', 'prefecture' = 'Kanagawa'

I cannot use GET as I am calling a modal that is common to all the href links, or may be I am unaware of an efficient method.
Here is the code,

**HREF LINKS**

```
<section id="area">
            <div class="container inner">
                <div class="train-line">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2> Kanto Area </h2>
                        <a href="#modal-work03" data-toggle="modal" name="tokyo" id="1" class="btn btn-large">Tokyo</a>
                        <a href="#modal-work03" data-toggle="modal" name="kanagawa" id="2" class="btn btn-large">Kanagawa</a>
                        <a href="#modal-work03" data-toggle="modal" name="chiba" id="3" class="btn btn-large">Chiba</a>
                        <a href="#modal-work03" data-toggle="modal" name="saitama" id="4" class="btn btn-large">Saitama</a>
                        <a href="#modal-work03" data-toggle="modal" name="ibaraki" id="5" class="btn btn-large">Ibaraki</a>                           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

**MODAL**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-work03" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-work03" aria-hidden="true">
```

.
.
.

Please advice on how to set a PHP session variable when a particular href link is clicked, so that I can use that info on other PHP pages.TIA

Comment: You tagged this with `ajax`, and that's exactly what you need. Just add a click handler to your `<a>`s and run a request in the background, sending along the chosen prefecture as GET param. Not sure what you mean by "I cannot use GET", why not?

Comment: yes, after researching, I figured I can accomplish it with ajax, but I am completely blank on how to pass a variable via ajax and set php session variable, any reference links ? TIA

Comment: Just run a request for, say, `index.php?action=setprefecture&prefecture=Tokyo`, then process the parameters in PHP. On the server, it doesn't make any difference whether the user clicked a link or the browser runs an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the onlclick event to your anchors:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" name="tokyo" id="1" class="btn btn-large"  onclick="setSessionVariable('Tokyo');return true;">Tokyo</a>
```

Add a javascript function (use jQuery or plain javascript) to the same page or in your included js file:

jQuery function:

```
function setSessionVariable(varname) {
    $.ajax({url: "setsession.php?vname="+varname, success: function(result){
        alert("ajax function success: " + result);
    }});
```

Javascript only function:

```
    function setSessionVariable(varname) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "setsession.php?vname="+varname, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

Add a php file called 'setsession.php'.
In the file you get the request var and set the session variable:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['prefecture'] = $_REQUEST['vname'];
echo("success");
exit(0);
?>
```

Of course you will want to do some validation and other stuff but that is up to you.

**UPDATE**

Changed &vname to ?vname

Comment: Thank you ! This works like a charm ! I have only made 1 edit .. changed &vname to ?vname and it worked !!

Comment: @prats1411  if you need to know if the ajax failed you should also include failed scenario notices in the ajax function, I did not include them in the answer for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I see is to use ajax and do an onclick of class `btn` or give them all a classname that is different from `btn`, mayble `modalbtn`. Then pass the name as it's data parameters and set the session there. I don't really see a way to do this with only php.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<section id="area">
    <div class="container inner">
        <div class="train-line">
            <div class="row">
                <h2> Kanto Area </h2>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" name="tokyo" id="1" class="btn btn-large">Tokyo</a>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" name="kanagawa" id="2" class="btn btn-large">Kanagawa</a>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" name="chiba" id="3" class="btn btn-large">Chiba</a>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" name="saitama" id="4" class="btn btn-large">Saitama</a>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" name="ibaraki" id="5" class="btn btn-large">Ibaraki</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    $('.btn-large').click(function(){
        sessionStorage.city = "";
        var city = $(this) .attr('name');
        sessionStorage.city = city;
    });
</script>
```

and now this data is stored inside a session variable and whichever page you want to access this variable you can do

```
sessionStorage.city
```

hope this helps